# Enumerating all n-tuples over a finite domain

Tags: algorithms, enumeration

I would like to create an algorithm which takes in an integer n and returns an array whose entries give all n-tuples of nonnegative integers each of which is at most n, so like

- `A[n][0] = [0,0,0,...,0]`,
- `A[n][1] = [1,0,0,...,0]`, ...,
- `A[n][n^(n+1)]=[n,n,n,...,n]`,

that kind of thing.

If n is small, I can manually create n-many for loops to do this, but in general I would like to allow n to be large. Is there an easy workaround? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursion.  Something like this:

```
def f(l, k):
    if l==0:
        yield []
    else:
        for i in range(k):
            for L in f(l-1, k):
                yield [i]+L
```

Here `f(l, k)` produces all lists of length `l` all of whose entries are in the range `0..k-1`.  The idea is that if you have all lists of length `l-1` (the output of `f(l-1, k)`) you can use that to generate all lists of length `l`, by using a for-loop.

If you're not familiar with that Python syntax, try this variant:

```
def f(l, k):
    if l==0:
        return [[]]
    t = [] 
    for i in range(k):
        for L in f(l-1, k):
            t.append([i]+L)
    return t
```

Note that `[i]` is a list containing a single element, `i`, and `+` is the list concatenation operator, so `[i] + L` is a list obtained by prepending the element `i` to the front of list `L`.

Comment: I do not understand this answer at all. What do you mean l in f(l-1,k)? Does [i]+1 even make sense?

Comment: I don't think necessarily yield was what was confusing me. Perhaps I'm too novice to even understand the answer (I wrote something about being a novice initially, but it was deleted by the mods), but there are just several things that confuse me about even the new code. I will explain my confusion in the next comment.

Comment: First, neither code runs without error in Sage, which understands Python (or at least has for me up until now). The first code runs if  I change `l=0`, to `l==0`. Even with this fix, if I then enter `f(2,5)`, it returns `[]`. Second, I don't understand how `l in f(l-1,k)` makes sense. In my mind, `f(l,k)` should be LISTS of length `l` in integers 0 to k-1. But `l` is the length, so how can it be both a list and the length of the list?

Comment: Okay, I got a running piece of code that does what I want it to based on your ideas. I edited your post with some syntactical corrections. I will now accept the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks much for your patience with all of the bugs in the code and for fixing the additional errors in the code, @Cass.   I've approved your edit.